# How to make a PDF portfolio from merged files

Tags: pdf

Adobe Acrobat has a feature where PDF files can be merged into a single portfolio document.  The various PDF files can be set out with a template, and clicking on its icon views the appropriate PDF.

Is there a command line tool on Linux that can create this kind of PDF?

I am **NOT** asking about simple concatenation, eg pdftk etc. I currently have that working.